# Como obter informações adicionais dos solvers do “scipy.integrate.ode”?

Tags: python

Eu estou comparando diferentes solvers ( dopri5, dop853, vode, etc) do “scipy.integrate.ode” e gostaria de saber se há  algum modo de obter informações como: numero de iterações, numero de passos utilizados, tempo de simulação, ...

Eu sei como conseguir esse tipo de informação no "scipy.integrate.odeint" usando, por exemplo, "infodict". No entanto, não descobri nenhuma maneira de fazer isso para os outros solvers que estou testando. A proposito, para descobrir o tempo necessário, estou usando "time.clock()" como abaixo (não sei se existe um modo melhor de fazer isso) :

```
time_start_RK4 = time.clock()                       

solver = ode(reactor_ode)
solver.set_integrator('dopri5')
solver.set_initial_value(Initial_conditions, t0)


solution_RK4 = np.empty((Nt, 8*N))
solution_RK4[0, :] = Initial_conditions
k = 1


while solver.successful() and solver.t < tf:
   solver.integrate(t[k])
   solution_RK4[k] = solver.y
   k += 1

time_elapsed_RK4 = (time.clock() - time_start_RK4)  

print(time_elapsed_RK4, 's')
```

Muito obrigado desde já!